# Как на клиенте android реализовать запрос текущего ip сервера?

Tags: android

Добрый день, как на android программно можно реализовать перед соединением с сервером запрос его текущего ip ?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть специальный класс [InetAddress](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/InetAddress.html) для работы с `Интернет-адресами`, определением доменного имени по адресу, определению адреса, по доменному имени и т.д.

В вашем случае надо использовать метод этого класса [getByName()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName(java.lang.String))